# How to check if a nested property exists?

Tags: javascript

What is the right way of checking if a nested property exists?

```js
if (openResult.notification) {
      if (openResult.notification.payload) {
        if (openResult.notification.payload.additionalData) {
          if (openResult.notification.payload.additionalData.sensorOpenWarning) {
            // now do sth with openResult.notification.payload.additionalData
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You could try the `&&` operator.

Comment: Possibly better duplicate target: [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631001/4642212).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to properly ask questions first. This question is likely to be downvoted / closed, since a simple google search reveals a solution to this problem in the first result (see comment above). Please do some research first.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch

```js
var obj;

try{
  console.log(obj.one.two.three.four)
}catch(e){
  console.log("obj is undefined")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this abbreviate form:

```
const prop2 = ((obj || {}).prop1 || {}).prop2;
```

Applied to your code would be:

```
const sensorOpenWarning = ((openResult || {}).notification || {}).payload || {}).additionalData || {}).sensorOpenWarning;
```